# Straight draw in heads up?

Tags: texas-hold-em, reading-hands, probability, heads-up

With a stack of 3000, 50/100 blinds, I was holding:

> 2 4 (not suited)

I'm big blind in a heads up game.  Opponent matches the big blind, so I end up playing a hand I'd never play otherwise.

Flop:

> 3 3 5 (Rainbow)

I see a straight draw, which is pretty nice.  Something around 32% if my odds calculations are right, plus potential outs with the remaining 2s and 4s, if he has something like AQ (meaning against a nonpair, I have 14 outs, which is in the 50% range, minus some for possibly hitting his pair also).  Plus the fact that there aren't cards much higher than mine - so more likely he doesn't have anything matching the table.

I bet 200, making the pot 400 at this point.

He moves all in, which is only about 2x pot size (and about half of my total stack).  Assuming I don't know anything about past patterns - is this an automatic 'match' or 'fold', or is this in the 'it depends' category?  If I take his bidding at his word, is this suggesting a particular hand?

His all-in was equivalent to a raise of 1200 for me, so the pot was 200+(my 200) + (his 1400) for total of 1800 at this point.  I'd be risking 1200 to win 3000 (and left with 1500, half my original stack, if I lose).

At the table, I put him on a higher pair (pair of Ts, say) and folded (as the straight draw itself seemed like a bad idea).

Comment: I have no idea on tags here, by the way, so please retag if this isn't right.

Comment: 1. Your question is badly formulated
2. Lack of data to answer you, i.e your stack

Comment: **Yes** Following what you said, that was a good fold.

Comment: Updated to include hand size.  I don't know why I bet 200 (full pot) btw - that seems high now that I look at it.  But... who knows.

Comment: Strange hand. Heads up any pair and any ace should raise in that position.  Still fold.  The could be on a 3 or 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always nice to get a *hard-to-detect draw* (unless you occasionally land against a miracle full house along the way; the *complete/check* action often leads to this), but players often overrate the *open ended straight draw (OESD)*.

That is, an OESD is overrated and should played with caution; it's true that you have around `32-35%` equity but this is only if you see the entire board; you only have `17%` (or say `20%` to ease pot-odds calculation) equity per-street.

So, your question:  **No** (Fold)

I don't know what others do with an OESD, but you should not gamble your entire stack with this, unless *you're short stacked*, say close to 5bb and need to act quickly.

Are you sure you have 14 outs? He may have the `5` or he simply paired the `3` since the action was *complete/check*.

- If i have a stack that can call him and not crippled if i lose, say lose only `30%` of my stack, i'll probably call here
- If we both have few blinds left, i certainly call here.
- If we both have good stacks, i'm going to fold here 100%.

So, for me it depends *on the stacks as well* and how it's going to cripple me if i'm not that desperate; It's just a draw.

That changes if you have some kind of combo draw, like

- OESD + flush draw
- OESD + 1 pair
- OESD + 2-high cards
- OESD + something more in general

**EDIT**

Based on the pot odds, you have been given around `30%` (28%) pot-odds where you may be `30-35%` dog to win. You certainly not crippled up if you lose, ending with around 15bb but the fact is *you have enough blinds* to keep going and *keep your opponent with short stack*; `30bb` is a good amount for better chances than this one. Don't make him the leader, you're not desperate yet. Calling here is out of desperation with around `30%` equity.

Comment: I certainly don't know if I truly have 14 outs - I assume his cards are part of the deck until I know otherwise (is that wrong?)  since they're unknown cards, unless I put him on a particular hand.

Comment: Overall though this is what I was looking for (though i'll leave it open to attract more answers).  I know I overrate OESD's - that's part of why I folded, knowing I probably was overrating my chances.  I think I fold hands actually that I perhaps shouldn't - like suited T9 - because I know I'm likely to misplay them when the cards come down and over-reach...

Comment: @Joe, you can't put him on any hand since the action was `complete/shove`, he played the stop'n'go move and you don't know what he has; he may have a hand or he may have `J2o` trash. I'll check the stacks on this since this is unclear; I'ts better for me folding here and shove it with a pair next hand since i just don't have fold equity anymore.

Comment: I was around 25-30 BBs, from what I recall.  IE, pot was 200 (100+100), my bet was 200, so with his match was 600, then all-in was another 1200, which I could match plus leave another 1200 to 1500.  So not a short stack for sure, but not a massive stack.

Comment: @Joe, update the question with the exact pot size before you call and the call amount, also your stacks for the others to see ;)

Comment: Done (somewhat from memory, but since this doesn't have to be precise we'll assume it's accurate).

Comment: @Joe, thanx for the very detailed edit ;) I edited my answer

Comment: You have 14 outs only against something like KQ, but given the action it's more likely that you have only 8. At the moment you have nut f---ing low, so you *have* to catch, and there's 0 implied odds, so it's purely a guessing game about your draw. 1200-for-3000 is pretty close *if* you have 14 outs, but I think a fold is pretty clearly the better play here.